# Measurability of function defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $A$ be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator defined on $L_2[a,b]$ by $$A(\varphi):=\int_{[a,b]}K(s,t)\varphi(t)d\mu_t$$where $K\in L_2([a,b]^2)$. The fact that $A(\varphi)\in L_2[a,b]$ is showed in the proof by Kolmogorov and Fomin (p. 461 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) by the following inequality, where $\psi:=A(\varphi)$:$$\int_{[a,b]}|\psi|^2d\mu\le\|\varphi\|^2\int_{[a,b]}\int_{[a,b]}|K(s,t)|^2d\mu_s d\mu_t$$I would think that, in order to apply a technique by majoration to prove the convergence of the integral of a positive function, we must know that the function is measurable. How do we see that $\psi$ is? I apologise if I ask a trivial question, but my textbook, which is supposed to be an introductory one, often tacitly uses facts never explained before. Thank you so much for any answer!

Comment: Please look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206344/is-the-integral-of-a-measurable-function-measurable

Comment: @FisiaiLusia Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is Tonelli's Theorem. For your case,

> **Theorem [Tonelli]**: Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$; let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue product measure on $[a,b]\times[a,b]$; and let $f$ be a non-negative jointly Lebesgue measurable function on $[a,b]\times[a,b]$. Then, for almost every $x$ the function $f_{x}(y)=f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[a,b]$, and for almost every $y$ the function $f_{y}(x)=f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[a,b]$. Furthermore $\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dm(x)$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dm(y)$ are Lebesgue measurable on $[a,b]$. And,
>   $$
>            \int_{a}^{b}\left[\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\,dm(x)\right]dm(y) =
>            \int_{[a,b]\times[a,b]}f\,d\mu = \int_{a}^{b}\left[\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)\,dm(y)\right]\,dm(x).
> $$
>   In particular, one of the three integrals is finite iff the other two are finite and, in all cases, the three are equal.