# Show that $M_t = ( \int_0^t b(w,u) dB_u)^2 - \int_0^t b^2 (w,u) du$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

$M_t = ( \int_0^t b(w,u) dB_u)^2 - \int_0^t b^2 (w,u) du$ where $B_u$ is a standard brownian motion and $b$ is such that $E[\int_0^t b^2(w,u) du]$ is finite.

I want to show that $M_t$ is a martingale with respect to the standard brownian filtration.

Showing that $M_t$ is $L^1$ is ok. But I can't prove that $E[M_t | F_s]=M_s$ for $t>s$. I'm pretty sure that one has to use Ito isometry, but even with that, I can't manage to arrive at $M_s$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity denote $\mathcal{I}_t := \int_0^t b(\omega, u)dB_u$ for each $t \geq 0$.

> The generalised Ito's isometry provides us with the following equality
>     $$ \mathbb{E}[\left.(\mathcal{I}_t - \mathcal{I}_s)^2 \right|
>  \mathcal{F}_s] =\mathbb{E}\left[\left. \int_s^t b^2(\omega,
>  u)du\right|\mathcal{F}_s\right] $$ for all $0\leq s < t <\infty$.

To prove this formula start first with the case when $b$ is a simple process, as it is done in the standard approach for proving Ito's isometry (the proof of the generalised Ito's isometry can be found in *Brownian motion and stochastic calculus* by Karatzas and Shreve in section 3.2.B. ) Then for the general case you take a sequence of simple processes $(b_n)$ to approximate $b$, that is, 
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t (b(\omega, s) - b_n(\omega, s))^2 ds\right] \to 0 \mbox{ as } n \to \infty $$
 and use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Then by applying the generalised Ito's isometry we can show that $\left( \mathcal{I}_t^2 -\int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale w.r.t $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left. \int_s^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=& \mathbb{E}[\left.(\mathcal{I}_t - \mathcal{I}_s)^2 \right| \mathcal{F}_s] \\=& \mathbb{E}[\left.\mathcal{I}_t^2  \right| \mathcal{F}_s]-2\mathcal{I}_s\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{I}_t | \mathcal{F}_s] + \mathbb{E}[\left.\mathcal{I}_s^2|\mathcal{F}_s  \right| \\=&
\mathbb{E}[\left.\mathcal{I}_t^2  \right| \mathcal{F}_s]-2\mathcal{I}_s^2 + \mathcal{I}_s^2\\ =&\mathbb{E}[\left.\mathcal{I}_t^2  \right| \mathcal{F}_s]- \mathcal{I}_s^2
\end{align*}
on the other hand 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left. \int_s^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right|\mathcal{F}_s\right] =& \mathbb{E} \left[\left. \int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du -  \int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du \right| \mathcal{F}_s\right]\\
=& \mathbb{E} \left[\left. \int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right| \mathcal{F}_s\right] -  \mathbb{E} \left[\left. \int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du \right| \mathcal{F}_s\right]\\=&  \mathbb{E} \left[\left. \int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right| \mathcal{F}_s\right] -  \int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du .\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$\mathbb{E}[\left.\mathcal{I}_t^2  \right| \mathcal{F}_s]- \mathcal{I}_s^2 = \mathbb{E} \left[\left. \int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du\right| \mathcal{F}_s\right] -  \int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du $$
and so 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left.\mathcal{I}_t^2 -\int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)du \right| \mathcal{F}_s\right] = \mathcal{I}_s^2 -  \int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du. $$

Comment: Can you explain why $E[\int_0^s b^2(w,u) du | F_S] = \int_0^s b^2(w,u) du$ ? I tend to say $E[\int_0^s b^2(w,u) du | F_S]= E[\int_0^s b^2(w,u) du]$

Comment: Sure. Let  $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra if a random variable $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable then $\mathbb{E}[X| \mathcal{G}] = X$. In order to obtain your claim, $X$ has to be independent from $\mathcal{G}$ and then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}[X]$. Here we have that the random variable $\int_0^s b^2(\omega, u)du$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable for all $s \geq 0$.

Comment: Why is it $\mathcal{F}_s$-mesurable ? This integral has nothing to do with Brownian motion right ? I'd say that it's independent from  $\mathcal{F}_s$

Comment: It depends on your assumptions on $b(\omega, t)$. In order to have $(M_t)$ well defined (we take an Ito integral of $b(\omega, t)$) so it is assumed that $(b(\cdot, t))_t$ is adapted with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_t)$. Now because the time integral of it exists and is finite, then this integral say $\int_0^t b^2(\omega, u)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for all $t \geq 0$. Check this as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206344/is-the-integral-of-a-measurable-function-measurable

Comment: I got it, thanks !